# Trying to parallelize hyperparameter tuning using pandas udf, but no success

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, facebook-prophet, pandas-udf

I've been trying to parallelize hyperparameter tuning for my prophet model for around 100 combinations of hyperparameters saved in the dataframe params_df.
I want to parallelize the hyperparameter tuning operation and have done the following:

```
schema = StructType([StructField('hyperparameters', StringType(), True),
                 StructField('mape', DoubleType(), True)]) 

@pandas_udf(schema,PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def grid_search(hyperparameters):
    train=valid_train_df.drop(columns='Series').copy()
    cutoffs=[train.loc[len(train)-5,'ds'],train.loc[len(train)-3,'ds']]
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters.reset_index(drop=True)
    params=ast.literal_eval(hyperparameters['hyperparameters'][0])

    prophet_test = Prophet(**params)

    for regressor in indep:
        prophet_test.add_regressor(regressor)

    prophet_test.fit(train[indep+['ds','y']])

    df_cv = cross_validation(model=prophet_test, horizon='62 days', cutoffs=cutoffs)
    df_cv['monthly_mape']=abs(df_cv['y']-df_cv['yhat'])/df_cv['y']
    mape=df_cv['monthly_mape'].mean()
    
    tuning_results = pd.DataFrame({'hyperparameters':str(params),'mape':mape},index=[0])

    return tuning_results
```

This part makes sure that I run pandas_udf on each set of hyperparameters.
spark_parallel_df is basically the spark dataframe for params_df containing the hyperparameters column.

```
run_udf_results=spark_parallel_df.groupby('hyperparameters').apply(grid_search)
hyperparameter_results=run_udf_results.toPandas()
```

But applying this seems is not giving me the desired results, as it is taking around 40 minutes to complete the hyperparameter tuning.

valid_train_df is the input dataframe used

I want to know if I'm missing something here?